# How do I extend the size of my root partition?

Tags: partitioning, resize

This is how my current hard drive looks. As you can see, I only have 1.5 GB left on my root partition and my computer slows down whenever multiple applications open or on a bit of heavy computing. I have almost 225 GB of available space on my other partitions.

I would like to know how should I change my partitions so that I can have more space in the root partition. So far I've kept the NTFS partitions so that I can install Windows at some point and make it a dual boot, but I'm very happy with Linux and intend to stick to it so I don't mind getting rid of the NTFS partitions.

However I would like to finally have at least two partitions. One where the Linux OS resides and the other where I keep all my data.

Please let me know how should I go about it without reformatting or losing my data. I will take all the backups of my Data just to be safe still.

I am relatively new to Linux.

Linux Partitions:

[image]

Comment: This is extremely easy if you don't need/use the empty partition /dev/sda3. Let me know, and I can give you a detailed instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command `apt-get auto-clean` may free up a substantial amount of space.  `apt-get clean` and `apt-get auto-remove` may free up additional space.

Creating a fairly large space for a `/var` partition and moving `/var` from the root partition should free up a fair amount of space.

`gpartd should be able to shrink the`/sda4`partition and move the`/sda3` partition.  This will take a lot of time as you want to move the starting point of the partitions.

I would consider shrinking `/sda4` to allow the `/sda3` partition to be moved to the end, but I don't know how well Windows would respond to that.

If you don't have anything you want on `/sda3` you could consider removing it and using it for the `/var` partition.  However, if grub is not your primary boot manager, you may render the system unbootable.